# MVC custom route question: Route one level higher?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a web application that I'm using a custom route to route http://domain/MyMVCSite/MyPage.ASP to route to a controller/action of my choosing.

I'm not TOO familiar with custom routing, but as it stands, this is my custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Page",
       "MyPage.ASP",
       new { controller = "KTASP", action = "KTASP", id = "" }
     );
```

As I said, this routes:

http://{domain}/MyMVCSite/MyPage.ASP

I would like for it to route:

http://{domain}/MyPage.ASP

Is this possible? How would I tweak the custom route?

My MVC site is being deployed as a virtual directory of a website on IIS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible without IIS configuration to rewrite the requests for "http://{domain}/MyPage.ASP" to go to your virtual directory.

Currently, your web application will never get considered, because that page is not within the virtual directory it is mapped to in IIS.   You need to either have routes (and a web app) at the root of the web site, or use URL rewriting to forward it to your vdir.

Comment: How would I go about configuring that in IIS?

My other option is to simply gut the ASP page, and add a Response.Redirect to my MVC page.
This is working, however it's not passing the HttpInput stream along as well. Once I get to the MVC controller, the HttpInput stream is empty.

Comment: @MichaelVelasquez I would use the URL Rewrite 2 module for IIS, which you can learn about here: http://forums.iis.net/1152.aspx  and here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/734/url-rewrite-module/

Comment: I'm using IIS6, and all the references to 7 make me assume that it's only a feature in 7?

Comment: There are a few options for IIS6 - http://www.isapirewrite.com/ and http://urlrewriter.net/ and http://iirf.codeplex.com/ .. the first is quite stable and costs, the second two are open source and I haven't used.

Comment: Before going the IIS route, is there simply any way to include the HttpInput stream in the Response.Redirect call that I put in the VBScript on the MyPage.ASP page?

I really appreciate all your help btw.

Comment: Not easily - `Redirect` is actually just telling the client browser to request a different page, the original input is lost - MyPage.ASP is never calling the new target page at all.  There are some things you can do, but they involve calling the target page from within MyPage.ASP - using a webrequest in .net (not sure how in vbscript).  But this starts to go to spending a good amount of time coding up a hack.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I'm trying to find the quickest/most painless way to do this. This is just a stop-gap fix for a client.
I'll look into deploying the MVC site at the root and hijack the MyPage.ASP page with my route that way.